# VBA How to check variable if it is set?

Tags: vba, ms-office

I try to initiate static variable to be 1 when the function is called first time. How to do it correctly? This is type mismatch error.

```
 Static clip_success As Integer
 If clip_success Is Nothing Then
    clip_success = 1
 End If
```

Comment: As soon as you define it `clip_success` will have a value of `0`.

Comment: `If clip_success = 0 Then`

Comment: OK, Thank you for reply.

Comment: `Nothing` is used with objects, such as ranges and worksheets ....... in your example, you should define `clip_success` as boolean (true/false)   .... then you can use (example) ........... `if clip_success then print "clip has been successful"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any primitive value type will be initialized with its default value. For numeric types that value is `0`; for strings, that's `""` (an empty string); for dates, that's `1899-12-30`. A `Boolean` is initialized to `False`.

Your static variable looks very much like a flag - should probably be a `Boolean`.

A `Variant` is initialized with the special value `Empty`.

Any object reference is initialized with `Nothing` / a null reference.

---

So:

```
Static clip_success As Long
If clip_success = 0 Then
   clip_success = 1
End If
```

Or

```
Static clip_success As Date
If clip_success = CDate(0) Then
   clip_success = DateTime.Now
End If
```

Or

```
Static clip_success As String
If clip_success = vbNullString Then
   clip_success = "success!"
End If
```

Or

```
Static clip_success As Variant
If IsEmpty(clip_success) Then
   clip_success = 1
End If
```

Or

```
Static clip_success As Object
If clip_success Is Nothing Then
   Set clip_success = New [some class]
End If
```